# UrlRewrite with 3 get request

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm working on a project and stuck on urlrewrite. I tried my best didn't find the answer, hope to get the solution here.

1. I am creating dynamic categories via single "category.php" page. I want to create 3 types of categories like this,

   - `mysite.com/maincategory.html` (This is main category there are 22 of them)
   - `mysite.com/maincategory/firstsubcategory.html` (apprx. 700-800 subcategories)
   - `mysite.com/maincategory/firstsubcategory/secondcategory.html` (apprx. 700-800 subcategories)
2. I created a "category.php" page which receives `$_GET['main']`, `$_GET['firstsub']` and `$_GET['second sub']` and used following codes in `.htaccess`,

   ```
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule (.*).html category.php?main=$1
   ```
3. I tried `mysite.com/categoryname.html` but didn't worked. I've successfully used above code for my other project and worked fine. But this is first time I'm working with `3 $_GET['main']` am not sure how it works.

Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the... let me check... yes yes, 10th time:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

And now the solution:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule download-game/(.*)\.html$ category.php?main=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html category.php?main=$1&firstsub=$2&secondsub=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html category.php?main=$1&firstsub=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.html category.php?main=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Please tell me if it works.

Comment: Hello Olivier Pons, first of all thank you very much for your reply. Second I made a mistake here while posting im using RewriteRule "(.*).html category.php?main=$1" and I posted RewriteRule "download-game/(.*).html category.php?main=$1". As i already told you i'm trying it very hard so i made a mistake in frustation. Sorry for that. Also good news is that somehow my urlrewrite for main category worked just now. So please assesit me to do for other two. Thanks

Comment: I made the correction in my code, "RewriteRule (.*).html category.php?main=$1" working fine for mysitename/categoryname.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to capture the category for A, the category and first subcategory for B, and the category, 1st subcategory and second subcategories for C. 
The solution below would work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)\.html$ category.php?main=$1&firstsub=$2&secondsub=$3 [L]
```

Edit:
Simplified code above.

Comment: Yes Ulrich Palha, That's what I want to do. Thanks for the answer. You urlrewrite code is difficult to understand for me. I hope it works perfectly. I'll try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I modified it to make it slightly simpler. Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Ulrich Palha, the first category is working perfectly with your code, but not the second and third. I tested my code, its working like this "sitename/category.php?main=categoryname&firstsub=subcategory" but when I use sitename/categoryname/subcategory.html it gives 404 not found error

Comment: Hi Ulrich Palha, You solution worked perfectly on Linux server, can you please suggest me the solution for same on windows server? Thaks for you answer.

Comment: It should work the same on windows too if you are using Apache. If it does not can you provide more details on what is not working.